# Editing of "hosts" file not effective

Tags: macos, unix

I've recently been trying to edit my hosts file to redirect URL's, effectively blocking them on my computer. I have years of programming experience, and experience with Terminal/nano, but I can't quite figure out why it won't redirect.

I have appended my hosts file like so (both /etc/hosts and /private/etc/hosts)

```
127.0.0.1       google.com
```

and I have flushed the dns cache like so

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

however, even after a restart it will not redirect. Any ideas on what might be the problem?

EDIT:

So the redirect works when I ping "google.com" (it attempts to ping 127.0.0.1). However, it will not redirect in my web browser. I suppose this narrows down the problem.

EDIT 2:

So now I have determined that the redirects will work in any other web browser, but not in safari. Any ideas? I'm about to clear browsing data in Safari and see if that helps.

**Solution is below**

Comment: Could the browser be using some proxy settings?

Comment: The browser isn't using any proxy settings, I've just checked

Comment: clmcleod: you should post your solution as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem. Really, you can edit the hosts file like normal and flush the cache as described. After doing these things however, be sure to clear all private data from your browser. Some browsers keep internal caches of popular websites you visit. Since I visit google.com so much, Safari had cached the homepage rather than doing a fresh DNS lookup. hope this help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Not for author but for people from search:

Read the

```
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

[NSS configuration file Manual page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)
if your `hosts` file does not work!

> Here is an example /etc/nsswitch.conf file:
>
> ```
>    passwd:         compat
>    group:          compat
>    shadow:         compat
>
>    hosts:          dns [!UNAVAIL=return] files
>    networks:       nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
>    ethers:         nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
>    protocols:      nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
>    rpc:            nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
>    services:       nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
> ```